# Query by ids or keys in datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Using python, I have a google datastore ndb model like this.

```
class Persona(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True)  
    names= ndb.StringProperty(default="")
    address = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
    city = ndb.StringProperty()
    count = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=0)
```

When I created the entities I used my own ids (sting) for each entity, so I can do queries (using remote_api) like this:

```
data_person.Person.query(data_person.Person.name=="Adam").fetch(10,keys_only=True)
```

And the result is:

```
[Key('Person', '16.240.886'), Key('Person', '17.722.453'), Key('Person', '13.627.225'), Key('Person', '18.223.406'), Key('Person', '18.460.819'), Key('Persona', '17.047.133'), Key('Person', '12.875.781'), Key('Person', '13.182.078'), Key('Person', '14.186.000'), Key('Person', '14.424.659')]
```

How can I query Ids (or Keys) in order to get vales lower (or higher) than an specific Id (or Key)

For example:

```
query(Person.id()<'16.240.886')  #I know this is wrong, is just understand the idea order to get all the keys lower then the specific id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
Person.query().filter(Person.key < ndb.Key(Person, '16.240.886'))
```

Comment: Thanks @Victor Is there a diference between: 
` Person.query().filter(Person.key<ndb.Key(Person,"16.240.886")).fetch(10,keys_only=True)`
and 

` Person.query(Person.key<ndb.Key(Person,"16.240.886")).fetch(10,keys_only=True)`

Comment: Actually the correct form is: Person.query().filter(Person.key<ndb.Key(Person,"16.240.886"‌​)).fetch(10,keys_onl‌​y=True)